# Is it possible to send pictures to the Tangle? What is the data limit per transaction?

Tags: tangle, ternary, legacy-protocol

As we all know, it is easily possible to convert ASCII to trytes. See this converter in the IOTA github: [Converter](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/blob/master/lib/utils/asciiToTrytes.js)
If I now want to convert a whole picture like one of the Iota logo to trytes, how is this possible? Is it possible at all?

Here is the picture I want to send to the tangle: [image: Iota Logo]
This picture should be small enough to send it via one transaction.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy protocol and given the latest updates it might make sense to only keep recent Shimmer, ShimmerEVM and IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, you can upload images or any files or other data to the tangle.

As long as their size is less than **2187 trytes** you can put them into one **tx** (=transaction). If they are bigger (=more trytes) than that, you can still send them by just putting them into **multiple txs that reference each other** (similar to a [bundles](https://domschiener.gitbooks.io/iota-guide/content/chapter1/bundles.html) for value txs).

So for example if you want to send data that is 3000 trytes, you have to put it into 2 txs.

You can use [this](https://laurencetennant.com/iota-tools/) tool to find out how many transactions you need for a certain picture/file.

Keep in mind that you have to do the [POW](https://www.iotasupport.com/whatisiota.shtml) for each tx which can be insanely high for big files/images.

You have to put the data into the place where you would put the signature for a spending tx: the `signature message fragment`

> `signatureMessageFragment` : String 2187-trytes signature message fragment.
>   In case there is a spent input, the signature of the private key is stored here. If no signature is required, it is empty (all 9's) and can be used for storing the message value when making a transfer.

https://domschiener.gitbooks.io/iota-guide/content/chapter1/transactions-and-bundles.html

### Convert binary image files (png, jpg, bmp) to trinary messages and vice versa

If you want to convert a picture to a IOTA message, you have to read the file and save it into a byte-array or similar (`byte[]` in Java/C#, `char*` in C, `bytes()` in python, `Uint8Array()`in JavaScript). I will not explain how to do that here as you can look it up on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) or just [duckduckgo/google](https://duckduckgo.com) it.

```
function String[] btop(bytes[]){
    // binary to presentation
}
```

converts the `bytes[]` to a string representation of the tryte message or multiple strings in case `message > 2187`
Now you can add this message/these messages to a transaction and attach them to the Tangle.

The receiver reads the message(s) from the Tangle and then uses a function like this:

```
function bytes[] ptob(String[]){
    // presentation to binary
}
```

to convert the trytes back to a `byte[]`, which can be written to a file.

### Practice

Using [iota-storage.net](http://iota-storage.net), I was able to upload your picture to the Tangle. Checkout their [GitHub](https://github.com/iota-storage/storage-web).

- [Picture](http://iota-storage.net/download/?id=FAVP9FYHIXJJH9XIA9WWCJXLCBFEIZFCBAI9XHJBWQ9H9COCPSYUUEPDEWECZZYUBAUUWHLERBAIYDTUW)
- [Transaction](https://thetangle.org/bundle/FAVP9FYHIXJJH9XIA9WWCJXLCBFEIZFCBAI9XHJBWQ9H9COCPSYUUEPDEWECZZYUBAUUWHLERBAIYDTUW)

Comment: OK thanks, but how do I convert a picture to trytes?

Comment: It depends on the format of the picture (jpg,png,svg,etc.). Basically just convert binary to ternary/trinary... I'll try to find something and edit the answer.

Comment: There is a site doing this http://iota-storage.net/ they have a github repository at https://github.com/iota-storage/storage-web