# Sending big payload in multiple messages

Tags: transaction, chrysalis

From [this question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/168/is-it-possible-to-send-pictures-to-the-tangle-what-is-the-data-limit-per-transa/171), I would like to know if there is an updated method to send big payload within the current IOTA network (chrysalis 1.5).

From the [docs](https://wiki.iota.org/learn/about-iota/data-transfer):

> Because messages in IOTA are not allowed to exceed a size of 32kb, the
> message must declare the size of its payload to the node... like you
> would need to report the weight of a package if you want to send it
> with a courier in advance.

My doubts:

- It is possible to declare the size of the message manually? For IOTA to somehow fragment the big payload into multiple messages?
- Is there any method described on the API to fragment messages? I tried to look for the bundle definition in the documentation, but I haven't found it.

In case it can help, I'm using Rust library to send messages through IOTA streams.

I guess the only option is to split the payload before sending and assemble it after receiving, right?

Thank you very much.